# rtmpdump not working on Ubuntu Server 14.10

Tags: server, 14.10, rtmp

I followed [these steps](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/customized-rtmpdump-binaries-patch-file-t16103.html) to patch `rtmpdump` with KSV's updates.  `rtmpdump` executes beautifully on my laptop but when I tried the same thing on my Ubuntu Server machine, `rtmpdump` hangs after `INFO: Connected...`(using the same command that worked on the laptop).  I'm sure that the patching worked because after successfully patching, I'm able to use the `-K` option, which didn't work before the patch.

How can I make `rtmpdump` work on the Ubuntu Server machine?

My ultimate goal is to automatically record a live stream M-F on the server and if there is a better way than `rtmpdump`, I'd love to hear about it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After I installed `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` it started working on the server